# require node modules at the file beginning

Tags: node.js, require

I had a habit of requiring all my node modules in the beginning of the app.js file.

```
var express=require('express'),
bodyParser = require( 'body-parser' ),
cookieParser = require( 'cookie-parser' ),
compression = require( 'compression' ),
.
.
```

But some modules are used for single jobs in a single function, so I can remove those from the beginning and place them inline.

```
var express=require('express'),
bodyParser = require( 'body-parser' ),
cookieParser = require( 'cookie-parser' ),
compression = require( 'compression' ),
.
.
function myfunc(){
require( 'https' ).get( "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret= ......
.
.
```

instead of

```
var express=require('express'),
bodyParser = require( 'body-parser' ),
cookieParser = require( 'cookie-parser' ),
compression = require( 'compression' ),
https=require('https'),
.
.
function myfunc(){
https.get( "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret= ......
.
.
```

My question: Which of these gives better performance?

Answer (score 2):

Modules Caching concept inside node.js says:

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means
>   (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get
>   exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same
>   file.

Documentation can be seen here [modules_caching](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching)

It means either choice of `require` is just different way of coding style.

Answer (score 1):

The `require` function is an synchronous operation. Which means that is blocking. It is better to use it in the beginning of your file in order to avoid blocking calls while your program runs. If a module is already `required` then it is cached so that operation won't be blocking. But most of the times it is preferable to use `require` on top of your module. This way you don't need to keep track of modules that have been cached in order to use `require` inside a function without side effects