# Side-effects of not loading node modules globally

Tags: node.js, commonjs

Normally, we require node modules like:

```
var dep = require('some-dependency');
function runner() {
  dep();
}
```

If we do like this:

```
function runner() {
var dep = require('some-dependency');
dep();
}
```

I know for fact it works, and there's nothing stopping me from doing this, except Eslint's [global-require](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/global-require) rule.

But is there any side effect in the latter pattern, considering how Node handles it internally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I got my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660713/require-node-modules-at-the-file-beginning).

**TL;DR**:
No side effect as such, except for the require operation being blocking, so you may not want to put it deep inside your app.

Answer (score 0):

If 'require' is placed on module level, the required module will execute upon require. 
But if 'require' is placed in a function, it won't execute upon require, unless your function is called.